# Replace cases in one dataset using cases from another file

Tags: replace, stata

I have a master data file that contains responses from English, German, and French respondents. The open-ended responses (OER) were sent to translators and they sent us back a  file with the original OER and English translation of those. Now I want to replace the "empty" columns reserved for English translation in my master data with the new information.

My approach was:

Create a loop in the translation file:

```
foreach var of varlist *englishtranslation* {
    rename `var' new_`var'
}
```

Then merge `` new_`var' `` into master data using respondent `ID`.

Replace non-missing cases in blank cols using info in `` new_`var' ``.

Drop `` new_`var' ``.

However, Stata keeps saying that the new variable names `` new_`var' `` are invalid:

> You attempted to rename q12_v1_995_oe_englishtranslation to
>   new_q12_v1_995_oe_englishtranslation.  That is an invalid Stata
>   variable name.

Do you have any recommendation on fixing that error or on another approach?

Many thanks,

EL

**Edit:** I understand that the variable name length limit is 32 and that variable has exactly 32 characters, hence the error when I tried to rename it. But I need to come up with a systematic way to name these variables because multiple people work on it and I don't want to mess with the agreed organization of the dataset.

Comment: The issue or organizing your team's workflow is one (or several) step(s) removed from the programming problem. There should be a relation of course. If Stata is the main application supporting the team's statistical work, then "agreed organization" should take that into account (I doubt this is your case). If the main application is other then Stata, but you need/want/desire to do use it, then you probably need to convince other team members of the "need" of using shorter names. At least, I don't know of a way to bypass this problem within Stata.

Comment: I wish that were the case! Unfortunately, the client insists on using these names and I was not in the position to negotiate with them on this issue *sigh*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new name has 36 characters. There's a limit of 32 (with Stata 12 and 13, at least).

An example reproducing your error:

```
clear
set more off

set obs 1

gen q12_v1_995_oe_englishtranslation = 99
gen new_q12_v1_995_oe_englishtranslation = 10
```

Solution: make the name shorter.

See `help varname` for details.

### Edit

On your question about renaming:

Try:

```
rename *englishtranslation *engtrans
```

See `help rename` and `help rename group` for details.

Comment: Hi Roberto,

Is there away for me to rename part of the varname? For example, rename "q12_v1_995_oe_englishtranslation" into "q12_v1_995_oe_engtrans"?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the "rename" issue.